# Is it possible to convert html to type node?

Tags: javascript

I return HTML and I need to append it to the element on page, but its not type node, is it possible to convert it?

`generateOptionMonths()` method's code was originally in the `createCheckpointModalHtml()` and everything was working, but the whole code was very complicated so I wanted to do it as a separate method. 
I don't get it why it is not working, considering it was the exact same code when it was in `createCheckpointModalHtml()` and it was working fine.

```
class CheckpointsArea {

   constructor(){
        this.monthsNames = this.generateOptionMonths();
   }

   createCheckpointModalHtml(){
        let chooseMonth = createElement("select", "select-month");
        chooseMonth.appendChild(this.monthsNames);//Error is here
   }

   generateOptionMonths(){
    let monthNames = this.getDaysAndMonth().map( date => {

        let month = createElement("option", "select-option");
        month.innerText = date.Name;

        return month
    });
    }

}
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: You should consider that `generateOptionMonths` does not return anything. Not saying that's the cause of your issues, but its not quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fix your code like so

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
    <script>
        class CheckpointsArea {
            constructor(){
                this.monthsNames = this.generateOptionMonths();
                console.log(this.monthsNames);
                this.createCheckpointModalHtml();
            }

            getDaysAndMonth() {
                return [{Name: 'foo'}, {Name: 'bar'}];
            }

            createCheckpointModalHtml(){
                let chooseMonth = document.createElement("select", "select-month");
                this.monthsNames.forEach(m => chooseMonth.appendChild(m));
                document.body.appendChild(chooseMonth);
            }

            generateOptionMonths(){
                return this.getDaysAndMonth().map( date => {
                    let month = document.createElement("option", "select-option");
                    month.innerText = date.Name;
                    return month;
                });
            }
        }
        const cp = new CheckpointsArea();
    </script>
</html>
```

You had 2 main issues.

1. You were attempting to call appendChild passing an array. Instead loop over the array and append each element.
2. `generateOptionMonths` wasnt returning anything. The lambda in the map function was but the function itself was not.

You were also not appending the select element to the document body.